# Meaning of int (*) (int *) = 5 (or any integer value)

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers

I cannot figure this out:

```
int main() {
    int (*) (int *) = 5;
    return 0;
}
```

The above assignment compiles with g++ c++11. I know that `int (*) (int *)` is a pointer to a function that accepts an `(int *)` as argument and returns an int, but I do not understand how you could equate it to 5. At first I thought it is a function that constantly returns 5 (from my recent learning in F#, probably, haha), then I thought, briefly, that the function pointer points to memory location 5, but that does not work, clearly, and neither does hex values.

Thinking that it could be because the function returns an int, and that assigning an int is ok (somehow), I also tried this:

```
int * (*) (int *) = my_ptr
```

where `my_ptr` is of type `int *`, the same type as this second function pointer, as in the first case with type int. This does not compile. Assigning 5, or any int value, instead of `my_ptr`, doesn't compile for this function pointer either.

So what does the assignment mean?

**Update 1**

We have confirmation that it is a bug, as shown in the best answer. However, it is still not known what actually *happens* to the value that you assign to the function pointer, or what happens with the assignment. Any (good) explanations on that would be very much appreciated! Please refer to the edits below for more clarity on the problem.

**Edit 1**

I am using gcc version 4.8.2 (in Ubuntu 4.8.2)

**Edit 2**

Actually, equating it to anything works on my compiler. Even equating it to a std::string variable, or a function name that returns a double, works.

**Edit 2.1**

Interestingly, making it a function pointer to any function that returns a data type that is not a pointer, will let it compile, such as

```
std::string (*) () = 5.6;
```

But as soon as the function pointer is to a function that returns some pointer, it does not compile, such as with

```
some_data_type ** (*) () = any_value;
```

Comment: Hmm...it doesn't look right, and clang doesn't accept it. Could be a gcc extension (or bug).

Comment: Probably because a function pointer is still only a memory pointer. If you try to invoke this method, it would probably give you a segfault.

Comment: but what does it actually do? what does it assign 5 to?

Comment: The declaration should have the same semantics as a regular pointer. `int* x = 5` is invalid and so should that be.

Comment: g++ compiles, but gcc not working: `error: expected identifier or '(' before ')' token`

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: @0x499602D Note that the code doesn't give a name to the pointer. With `int *x = 5` you named it `x`. With  `int * (*x) (int *) = 5` it will not compile. (albeit that will compile as C code).

Comment: Can you please provide a fuller context? Your assignment *doesn't* compile. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: This is not an assignment -- the thing to the left of the `=` is not a valid expression (of any type).  Nor is it a valid declaration (no declarator), so it *should* be a syntax error.  But gcc seems to accept it and ignore it (the generated code is noop).  A bug in gcc?

Comment: How can **one line** compile - in answer to OP's deleted comment "this compiles"?

Comment: @WeatherVane sorry, I'm new to StackExchange, just learning the ins and outs of the formatting. But basically if I just define the main function, and put that line in, and say return 0, it compiles. Apologies for the bad formatting in my questions/comments :/

Comment: @WeatherVane one line can easily compile. `int x = 5;` compiles fine. (though it will not link). Presumably the OP has this one line placed in  a function body though.

Comment: Looks like it's a bug. For same reason `int (*) (int *);` also compiles while it is also invalid.

Comment: Your recent edit is exactly what I compiled before my first comment. It's not enough to compile. Please show what you are trying to do!

Comment: @nos what is the point of posting an irrelevant one line that does compile?

Comment: @WeatherVane really not trying to do anything with this (not yet, hehe). Just saw something that I didn't understand and played around with it.

Comment: Interestingly, G++ even compiles it without a semicolon: `int main(){ int (*)() = 5 }`.

Comment: @WeatherVane The question should not be tagged with the C tag, since none of the C compilers will accept that code. However, for some reason g++ accepts it.

Comment: @KonradKapp when compiling, always enable **warnings**, `-Wall -Wextra` at a minimum, (e.g. `g++ -Wall -Wextra -o yourprog yourfile.cpp`)

Comment: Reduced testcase: `int(*) = 5;` and `int(*);`

Comment: It's probably worth specifying a version of `g++`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I did enable warnings, but none show up at compilation.

Comment: Looks like https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60680

Comment: Hmm Shot in the dark: "Anonymous function pointer initialized with address 5" vs `int (*x) (int *) = (int (*) (int *)) 5;` which in named function pointer initialized with matching type casted `5`.

Comment: @T.C. it seems you came up first with the explanation (or a proof of it). Do you want to make your own stand-alone answer so I can specify it as the most helpful, or should I vote ouah's answer as best, where he references you?

Comment: @KonradKapp Feel free to accept one of the existing answers.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

It's a bug in g++.

```
 int (*) (int *)
```

is a type name.

In C++ you cannot have a declaration with a type name without an identifier.

So this compiles with g++.

```
 int (*) (int *) = 5;
```

and this compiles as well:

```
 int (*) (int *);
```

but they are both invalid declarations.

**EDIT**:

[T.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2756719/t-c) mentions in the comments bugzilla bug [60680](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60680) with a similar test case <s>but it has not yet been approved</s>. The bug is confirmed in bugzilla.

**EDIT2**:

When the two declarations above are at file scope g++ correctly issues a diagnostic (it fails to issue the diagnostic at block scope).

**EDIT3**:

I checked and I can reproduce the issue on the latest release of g++ version 4 (4.9.2), latest pre-release version 5 (5.0.1 20150412) and latest experimental version 6 (6.0.0 20150412).

Comment: MSVC rejected the edited posted code with `error C2059: syntax error : ')'`

Comment: If it is a type name, why doesn't 'int (*) (int *) int_func;' work?

Comment: For the GCC bugzilla, "NEW" is a confirmed bug. (Unconfirmed bugs are "UNCONFIRMED").

Comment: @KonradKapp: it works just fine if you say `int (*int_func)(int *);`  which declares a function pointer named `int_func`.

Comment: @T.C. My understanding of "New" Status is it has not yet been processed. Any pointer?

Comment: @ouah Check the history of that bug.

Comment: I'd also say the bug matches perfectly this case. The bug seems to have been accepted.

Comment: @KonradKapp C++ uses infix notation for placing the identifier; same reason it is `int x[5];` and not `int[5] x;`

Comment: @MattMcNabb thanks, just lost my wits there for a few moments haha

Comment: @ouah I'm voting this answer as the best, since it gives proof that it is a bug (through T.C.'s comment). I would still like to know what actually **happens** to the number/value that you assign to the invalid declaration.

Comment: @KonradKapp the whole invalid declaration statement is actually optimized out.

Comment: @ouah any good resources on how such optimizations might work? Quite curious as to what happens under the hood.

Answer (score 28):

It is not valid C++.  Remember that because your particular compiler happens to compile it doesn't make it valid.  Compilers, like all complex software, sometimes have bugs and this appears to be one.

By contrast `clang++` complains:

```
funnycast.cpp:3:11: error: expected expression
    int (*) (int *) = 5;
          ^
funnycast.cpp:3:18: error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
    int (*) (int *) = 5;
             ~~~ ^
funnycast.cpp:3:19: error: expected expression
    int (*) (int *) = 5;
                  ^
3 errors generated.
```

This is the expected behavior because the offending line is not valid C++.  It purports to be an assignment (because of the `=`) but contains no identifier.

Answer (score 9):

As other answers have pointed out, it is a bug that

> `int (*) (int *) = 5;`

compiles. A reasonable approximation of this statement that would be expected to have a meaning is:

> `int (*proc)(int*) = (int (*)(int*))(5);`

Now `proc` is a pointer-to-function that expects the address `5` to be the base address of a function that takes an `int*` and returns an `int`.

On some microcontrollers/microprocessors `5` might be a valid code address, and it might be possible to locate such a function there.

On most general-purpose computers, the first page of memory (addresses `0-1023` for 4K pages) are purposely invalid (unmapped) in order to catch `null` pointer accesses.

Thus, while behavior depends on the platform, one can reasonably expect a page fault to occur when `*proc` is invoked (e.g., `(*proc)(&v)`). Before the time at which `*proc` is invoked, nothing unusual happens.

Unless you are writing a dynamic linker, you almost certainly shouldn't be numerically calculating addresses and assigning them to pointer-to-function variables.

Answer (score 2):

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/cc1plus.exe -da so.cpp
```

This command line generates a lot of intermediate files. The first of them, `so.cpp.170r.expand`, says:

```
...
int main() ()
{
  int D.2229;
  int _1;

;;   basic block 2, loop depth 0
;;    pred:       ENTRY
  _1 = 0;
;;    succ:       3

;;   basic block 3, loop depth 0
;;    pred:       2
<L0>:
  return _1;
;;    succ:       EXIT

}
...
```

This still doesn’t answer what happens exactly, but it should be a step in the right direction.

Comment: Interesting. What is the purpose of these intermediate files?

Comment: @KonradKapp To produce machine code from human code is quite a complex process (especially if you want your compiler to optimise its output). Since compiling is so complex, it isn't done in one step, most compilers have some form of Intermediate Representation (IR).

Comment: Another reason for having an IR is that if you have a well-defined IR you can separate front-end and back-end of your compiler. (E.g. front-end compiles C to your IR, back-end compiles IR to Intel machine code. Now if you want to add ARM support you only need a second back-end. And if you want to compile Go, you only need a second front-end, and on top of that the Go compiler immediately supports both Intel and ARM since you can reuse both back-ends.

Comment: @11684 OK, makes sense. Very interesting. I could not determine what language Roland gave in this answer though...it looks like some kind of assembly mixed with C.

Comment: IR needn't be printable; I have no idea what gcc uses, this may merely be a printable representation @KonradKapp